# .NET Core 2.1 TFS build failed on restore step

Tags: tfs, .net-core

I try to build my .NET Core proj in TFS but the build failed in restore step with 
**Error: Failed which: Not found dotnet: null** error.

.NET Core version: 2.1.3
TFS version: 15.112.26307.0
Build definition: .NET Core (PREVIEW)

Comment: Can you build the .Net Core project successfully on the agent machine locally? What about other agents? You can try to deploy a new agent then check the issue again. Also check if the agent service account is in the local administrators group, if not , try adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you don't have the .NET Core SDK installed on your build machine.

Can you make sure you have the latest version of the .NET Core SDK? For example, you should be able to log in to your build machine and run `dotnet` from the command line, and get basic usage information.

You can download the latest version of the .NET Core SDK at https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows.

Comment: Any ideas if I have that, and can successfully run `dotnet build` manually on the build server, but get this error using the dotnet build step in TFS Build?