# .NET Core Build Step Failing

Tags: tfs, .net-core

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380708/net-core-2-1-tfs-build-failed-on-restore-step), I am getting

`##[error]Error: Failed which: Not found dotnet: null`

when trying to build our .NET Core application. I am using the `dotnet build` step (.NET Core Preview) with TFS 2017 Update 1. The build account is a local administrator. I can run the command manually on the build server and it works. I can also open and build the solution in Visual Studio 2017 on the server and it all works.

I have set the command to build, and the Project(s) to various things, including `**\projectname.csproj`, `**\solutionname.sln`, `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\projectname.csproj`, and others. I do not have the recommended `.NET Core SDK Installer` task available to add to the definition.
The entirety of my log for the step:

```
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0915248Z ##[section]Starting: dotnet build
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z Task         : .NET Core (PREVIEW)
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z Version      : 0.3.1
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2019-04-08T16:17:22.0935207Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-08T16:17:22.4985639Z ##[error]Error: Failed which: Not found dotnet: null
2019-04-08T16:17:22.5075597Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet build
```

Edit: I have upgraded our TFS server from 2017U1 to 2017U3.1. I now have a non-preview version of the .NET Core Build Task, but I do not have a task to install a specific version of the .NET Core SDK, as has been suggested I use. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Go to Command Prompt and type "dotnet --version". What does it say?

Comment: @Amel version is 2.1.602

Comment: Is this output from your build server? Output from dotnet --version from your build server should look more like this https://gist.github.com/hiraldesai/8d0623f461aab391dce253188f65d35c.

It looks like your build server has a very old version of the SDK - why do you need to use dotnet core preview anyway?

Try explicitly installing a specific SDK version first then run dotnet build, you can use task called ".Net Core SDK Installer" task for it. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfivx.png

Comment: what is your .net core version in projectname.csproj ?

Comment: @komluk .NET Core 2.1

Comment: @HiralDesai Yes, from the build server. When I type "dotnet --version" in a command prompt, all I get is the value. I downloaded and installed it today, from Microsoft's website dotnet-sdk-2.1.602-win-x86.exe (and the x64 version).

Comment: That's quite weird. It looks like the server is not taking the latest install as the current runtime. Could have something to do with the user you're running this as. Have you tried using the ".Net Core SDK Installer" task? It will force the entire build pipeline to use the specified version of SDK. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @HiralDesai I don't have that step to choose from when editing a build definition.

Comment: I'm out of ideas unfortunately. Maybe the TFS installation needs an upgrade to get access to these tasks? I use Azure Dev Ops (the cloud version of TFS), so these tasks are automatically made available to my instance. 

The task I'm talking about is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts). It is an official task published by Microsoft only.